# Angular 8 - routerLink vs [routerLink] in combination with routerLinkActive problem

Tags: angular, angular-routing

When I use the following code, the routerLinkActive works but it fails to build.

```
<a mat-button routerLinkActive="mat-raised-button [routerLink]="login">Inloggen</a>
```

When I use the following code, the routerLinkActive doesn't work but building succeeds.

```
<a mat-button routerLinkActive="mat-raised-button" routerLink="login">Inloggen</a>
```

How can I fix this problem? If I use the first code, my Azure DevOps build pipeline doesn't finish because of the error.

Build error: "Property 'login' does not exist on type 'LoginHeaderComponent'."

Foudn the problem. I forgot a '/' for the second line of code.

Comment: Can you include the build errors you are receiving in your question

Comment: `[routerLink]="login"` should be `[routerLink]="'login'"`

Comment: I have included it.

Comment: In the first one, `login` is an Angular expression, and is thus evaluated to `yourComponent.login` which is probably undefined (and won't compile in prod mode). It's thus incorrect. In the second one, it's not an angular expression at all, and the string "login" is thus passed to the routerLink directive. It's probably what you want. But what do you mean by "doesn't work"? What is the current URL (displayed in the browser location bar), what do you expect to happen and what happens instead?

Comment: @JBNizet The second one doesn't raise my button because I don't use [] apparantly.. because with [] it raises the button but build fails in my ci/cd on azure devop.s

Comment: No. It doesn't raise the button because the path of the generated link isn't a prefix of the current path. Again, what is the current URL (displayed in the browser location bar), what do you expect to happen and what happens instead? Do you understand what routerLinkActive does?

Comment: @JBNizet current url is localhost:4200/login, when im on that page I want the button to raise.

Comment: Re-read Stavm, and JB Nizet comment, your answer is there.

Answer (score 2):

Try writing it like this:

```
<a mat-button routerLinkActive="mat-raised-button" [routerLink]="['/login']">Inloggen</a>
```

Angular is going to take your path fragments and generate a URL. If that url matches what your current location is, then it'll add the class you specify

https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink

**Why your original attempts didn't work like you expected.**

The reason this doesn't work, is because it is reading `login` as a template variable.

```
<a mat-button routerLinkActive="mat-raised-button" [routerLink]="login">Inloggen</a>
```

The reason this doesn't work is because it is trying to build a path that is relative to your currently path, as in "/login"

```
<a mat-button routerLinkActive="mat-raised-button" routerLink="login">Inloggen</a>
```

You might try this and see if it works, but I prefer the syntax of my first suggestion since it matches the documenation:

```
<a mat-button routerLinkActive="mat-raised-button" routerLink="/login">Inloggen</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to bind `[routerLink]` with `login` property which does not exist in your component.

You can create a property in the component and assign your link to it or if `login` is the URL then you need to remove binding like: `routerLink="/login"`

The `routerLinkActive` might only work if your route path matches the `login` path you have in `routerLinkActive` and becomes active.

`routerLinkActive` only adds a CSS class if the URL is `login`.

Comment: So what should I do? I dont want to use a property in my component file, I just want to say routerLink="login". But apparantly the routerLinkActive doesnt raise my button..

Comment: @MYil try `routerLink="/login"`